# Use the identity $(r+1)^3-r^3\equiv3r^2+3r+1$ to find $\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Use the identity $(r+1)^3-r^3\equiv3r^2+3r+1$ to find $$\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)$$

I can obtain $$\sum_{r=1}^n3r^2+3r+1=(n+1)^3-1$$

and I think the next step is

$$3\sum_{r=1}^nr(r^2+1)+\frac13=\left((n+1)^3-1\right)$$

But how do I deal with the constant 3 at the end of the LHS and also tidy up the answer to get $\frac13n(n+1)(n+2)$?

Comment: Hint: break up $\sum_{r=1}^n(3r^2+3r+1)$ as $\sum_{r=1}^n(3r^2+3r)+\sum_{r=1}^n(1)$; you should be able to sum the latter easily enough. :-) Then subtract it from your RHS and divide by three...

Comment: You’ve a major algebra error in your last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $3$ is no problem, though it should be $\frac13$: you have (after corrections)

$$3\sum_{r=1}^n\left(r(r+1)+\frac13\right)=(n+1)^3-1\;,$$

so

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\left(r(r+1)+\frac13\right)=\frac13\left((n+1)^3-1\right)\;,$$

and

$$\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)=\frac13\left((n+1)^3-1\right)-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac13=\frac13\left((n+1)^3-1-n\right)\;;$$

now just multiply out and simplify. If you can’t directly massage it into the desired form, multiply that out as well to show that the two are the same.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$r(r+1)=\frac{1}{3}((r+1)^3-r^3-1)$$
so 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{r=1}^n((r+1)^3-r^3)-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{r=1}^n1=\frac{1}{3}((n+1)^3-1)-\frac{n}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$3r^2+3r=3r(r+1)$$ and $$n(n+1)(n+2)=\dfrac{1}{4}n(n+1)(n+2)[(n+3)-(n-1)]\\=\dfrac{1}{4}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-\dfrac{1}{4}(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$$